# Rails: Module failing to autoload, raises NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload, wizard

I am currently building a multi-step form using rails and decided to do so by creating a class for each step of the form, and placing all of these classes inside a module named IntroQuizSteps. So far my module is very simple, including a "Base" class and a "StepOne" class which is a child of "Base". I opened up my rails console and tried to create a new instance of my "Base" class (using the command IntroQuizSteps::Base.new) just to see if everything was working but each time I receive the error "NameError: uninitialized constant IntroQuizSteps". I am not sure why this is happening since this module exists inside the app/models folder and to my knowledge, everything inside the "app" directory should be autoloaded. Any help on how I could successfully include this module in my project would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code from my IntroQuizSteps module inside the folder app/models/wizards:

```
module IntroQuizSteps

  class Base
    include ActiveModel::Model
  end

  class StepOne < Base

    attr_accessor :own

    validates :own, presence: true

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoload mechanism of Rails using its conventions to load module. As conventions of Rails, your file name and module name should match. So that, change `app/models/wizards` to `app/models/intro_quiz_steps` will work.